# Some clarification needed on Jenkins code

Tags: java, jenkins

```
def reportPath = build.getWorkspace().child("HealthTestResults.html")
msg.setContent(reportPath.readToString(), "text/html");
```

I know that `getWorkspace(), child() , setContent()` are Java methods. I understand what they do, I looked at the Javadoc. But what type is `reportPath` ? Are two different languages being mixed here ?

Why is `def` used to define `reportPath` ?

Comment: Are you using any plugins?

Comment: Looks like [Groovy](http://www.groovy-lang.org/style-guide.html), which can look a lot like Java.  The `def` keyword gives it away.

Comment: So Groovy and Java can be mixed ?

Comment: It is Groovy indeed.

Answer (score 0):

It is Groovy:

https://github.com/jenkinsci/email-ext-plugin/blob/master/src/main/resources/hudson/plugins/emailext/templates/groovy-html.template

From here: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Email-ext+plugin

The scripts are particularly powerful since they provide a hook into the Jenkins API including hudson.model.AbstractBuild and hudson.model.AbstractProject